# Error: g_ptr_array_add: assertion 'rarray' failed on c, using g_ptr_array

Tags: c, glib

I'm trying to add a custom structure to a g_ptr_array defined as

```
union response {
    int address; 
    entry_p ent;
};

typedef struct quad_{
    char * operation;
    union response resp;
    entry_p arg1;
    entry_p arg2; 
}quad;
```

The problem is that when using the function

`g_ptr_array_add(gaQuadList,(gpointer)s_quad);`

i get the following warning:

> GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_add: assertion 'rarray' failed

And thus when using

```
    s_quad = (singleQuad)g_ptr_array_index(gaQuadList,0);
```

causes a segmentation fault

The question i have is wether the structure is not inserted on the g_ptr_array or i'm not inserting correctly the structure on the array

Things that i've checked are that i can print a quad individually, the end goal here is that i can use the foreach function to print every single element of the array

Comment: You didn't even show what `gaQuadList` is. This is far from a [mcve].

Comment: sorry about that, tried to make it as compact as possible since the implementation is a big project spanning multiple files, gaQuadList is a gPtrArray declared to store the structure declared as follows

`GPtrArray * gaQuadList;`

Also, im going to correct this, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

The assertion failure is what you need to look at to diagnose this problem.

> GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_add: assertion 'rarray' failed

Looking at [the code for `g_ptr_array_add()`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/garray.c#n1383) shows that this assertion failure means that `gaQuadList` is `NULL`. i.e. You haven’t allocated the `GPtrArray` instance in the first place, or it has been overwritten with `NULL` somehow.

Are you calling `g_ptr_array_new_with_free_func()` anywhere beforehand to allocate the array?

Comment: Yep, rookie mistake, didn't initialized the gptrArray, im gonna read more carefully the API, (And also correct the question) but effectivelly the inicialization was missing